# php form to email, no working knowledge of PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I have no knowledge of PHP at all and am in desperate need of help. I have trawled the web for working examples but none of them are working for me. I need to send the data in the form to an email. I have 3 php files: index.php, contact.php and thank-you.php. Both the index and the contact page have forms on them and after sending the user is directed to the thank-you.php page. I am using localhost (MAMP) but i have also uploaded the website to [this domain](http://sukhysingh.co.uk). Please tell me what I am doing wrong. The following code is located in the contact.php file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title> Legal Active - Contact Us </title>
    <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Index">
    <meta name="keywords" content="personal inury specialist, accident,
    accident claims, claim, personal injury, claim today,">
    <meta name="author" content="Sukhvir Singh">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,
    shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/main.css">
    <!-- Animate.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
    href="../../css/animate.css-master/animate.min.css">
    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel='shortcut icon' href='favicon.png' type='image/x-icon'/>
    <script src="http://localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- Header Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-header-custom navbar-header-bg-custom">
        <ul class="navbar-header-icon nav navbar-nav pull-md-left">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link navbar-header-link hidden-dm-down"
     href="#"> 
                    <i class="navbar-header-link__icon--lg fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link navbar-header-link hidden-sm-down" href="https://twitter.com/search?src=typd&amp;q=legal%20active%20ltd"> 
                    <i class="navbar-header-link__icon--lg fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link navbar-header-link hidden-sm-down" href="#"> 
                    <i class="navbar-header-link__icon--lg fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-xs-right">
        <li class="nav-item hidden-md-up">
            <h5 class="navbar-header-link nav-link navbar-header-link--span"> Have a Question? </h5>
            <a class="nav-link navbar-header-link" href="tel:01618852353"> Call us NOW 
                <i class="navbar-header-link__icon fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"> </i> 0161 885 2353
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item hidden-sm-down">
            <h5 class="navbar-header-link nav-link navbar-header-link--lg--span"> Have a Question? </h5>
            <a class="nav-link navbar-header-link navbar-header-link--lg" href="tel:01618852353"> Call us NOW 
                <i class="navbar-header-link__icon--lg fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"> </i> 0161 885 2353
            </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>


   <!-- Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-custom bg-custom">
      <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-md-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar4" aria-controls="exCollapsingNavbar2" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <i class="navbar__icon fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-sm" id="exCollapsingNavbar4">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-xs-left col-xs-12">
          <li class="nav-item active col-xs-12 col-md-2 offset-md-1">
            <a class="nav-link" href="index.php"> HOME </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item btn-group col-xs-12 col-md-3">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn dropdown-toggle nav-link" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    TYPES OF CLAIMS
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="road-traffic-accident.html"> ROAD TRAFFIC ACCIDENTS </a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="Slips-Trips-and-Falls.html"> SLIPS TRIPS &amp; FALLS </a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="accident-at-work.html"> ACCIDENT AT WORK <span class="sr-only">(current)</span> </a>
                </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item col-xs-12 col-md-3">
            <a class="nav-link" href="work-with-us.html"> WORK WITH US </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item col-xs-12 col-md-1">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"> CONTACT </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item col-xs-12">
            <a class="nav-link hidden-md-up" href="#">
                <i class="nav-link__icon fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item col-xs-12">
            <a class="nav-link hidden-md-up" href="https://twitter.com/search?src=typd&amp;q=legal%20active%20ltd">
                <i class="nav-link__icon fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item col-xs-12">
            <a class="nav-link hidden-md-up" href="#">
                <i class="nav-link__icon fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>


    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="contact">
          <h3 class="contact__h3"> CONTACT US </h3>
          <div class="contact__divider"> </div>
          <div class="contact__text col-xs-12 col-md-5">
            Please use the form to tell us what you are enquiring about and somebody from our team will call you shortly.
          </div>
          <div class="contact__form form col-xs-12 col-md-5 offset-md-1">
            <form class="form-group" id="contact__form" action="thank-you.php" method="POST">
              <input type="text" class="input form-control fullName" placeholder="Full Name" name="fullName">
              <input type="tel" class="input form-control number tel" placeholder="Contact Number" name="contactNumber">
              <input type="text" class="input form-control email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email">
              <textarea class="input col-xs-12 message" placeholder="Your Message" name="message"></textarea>
              <button type="submit" class="form__btn btn btn-secondary"> SEND </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <nav class="navbar bg-footer">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav footer__nav">
                    <img class="footer__nav__logo col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3 pull-xs-right pull-md-left" src="../../assets/legal-active-logo-large.png" alt="Logo"/>
                    <li class="footer__nav-item nav-item col-xs-12 col-md-5 pull-xs-right"> Legal Active</li>
                    <li class="footer__nav-item nav-item col-xs-12 col-md-5 pull-xs-right"> Magnus House, 8 Ashfield Road, Cheadle, Cheshire, SK8 1BB </li>
                    <li class="footer__nav-item nav-item col-xs-12 col-md-5 pull-xs-right"> Registered in England &amp; Wales - Company No. 123 4567</li>
                    <li class="footer__nav-item nav-item col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-5 pull-xs-right"> All Rights Reserved &copy; Legal Active </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>




    <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script src="../../scss/bootstrap-4/js/tests/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../scss/bootstrap-4/js/tests/vendor/tether.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../scss/bootstrap-4/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../js/custom-js.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have now removed  the php code from contact.php to thank-you.php.
Here is the code located in than-you.php:

```
<?php

$to_mail = "sukhy87@me.com";

$mail_sent = 0;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo "the form was submitted";

$name = trim(strip_tags($_POST['fullName']));
if($name == "")
    $error = true;

$email = trim(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
if($email == "")
    $error = true;

$phone = trim(strip_tags($_POST['tel']));
$message = trim(strip_tags($_POST['message']));


if($error != true){
    $header = 'From: "Legal Active Website" <no-replylegalactive.co.uk>'."\r\n";


    $subject = "New Enquiry";

    $message = "New Contact message, received from: <br /> \n ";
    $message .= "<b>Name</b> ".$name."<br /> \n";
    $message .= "<b>Email</b> ".$email."<br /> \n";

    $message .= "<b>Phone</b> ".$phone."<br /> \n";

    $message .= "<b>message</b> ".$message."<br /> \n";

    if(@mail($to_mail,$subject,$message,$header))
    {
        echo "mail sent";
        $mail_sent = 1;
    }
    else echo "mail not sent";
} else {
    echo 'validation error';
}
}
?> 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title> Legal Active - Contact Us </title>
    <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Index">
    <meta name="keywords" content="personal inury specialist, accident, accident claims, claim, personal injury, claim today,">
    <meta name="author" content="Sukhvir Singh">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/main.css">
    <!-- Animate.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/animate.css-master/animate.min.css">
    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel='shortcut icon' href='favicon.png' type='image/x-icon'/>
    <script src="http://localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Header Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-header-custom navbar-header-bg-custom">
        <ul class="navbar-header-icon nav navbar-nav pull-md-left">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link navbar-header-link hidden-sm-down" href="#"> 
                    <i class="navbar-header-link__icon--lg fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link navbar-header-link hidden-sm-down" href="https://twitter.com/search?src=typd&amp;q=legal%20active%20ltd"> 
                    <i class="navbar-header-link__icon--lg fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link navbar-header-link hidden-sm-down" href="#"> 
                    <i class="navbar-header-link__icon--lg fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-xs-right">
        <li class="nav-item hidden-md-up">
            <h5 class="navbar-header-link nav-link navbar-header-link--span"> Have a Question? </h5>
            <a class="nav-link navbar-header-link" href="tel:01618852353"> Call us NOW 
                <i class="navbar-header-link__icon fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"> </i> 0161 885 2353
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item hidden-sm-down">
            <h5 class="navbar-header-link nav-link navbar-header-link--lg--span"> Have a Question? </h5>
            <a class="nav-link navbar-header-link navbar-header-link--lg" href="tel:01618852353"> Call us NOW 
                <i class="navbar-header-link__icon--lg fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"> </i> 0161 885 2353
            </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>


   <!-- Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-custom bg-custom">
      <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-md-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar4" aria-controls="exCollapsingNavbar2" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <i class="navbar__icon fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-sm" id="exCollapsingNavbar4">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-xs-left col-xs-12">
          <li class="nav-item active col-xs-12 col-md-2 offset-md-1">
            <a class="nav-link" href="index.php"> HOME </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item btn-group col-xs-12 col-md-3">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn dropdown-toggle nav-link" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    TYPES OF CLAIMS
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="road-traffic-accident.html"> ROAD TRAFFIC ACCIDENTS </a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="Slips-Trips-and-Falls.html"> SLIPS TRIPS &amp; FALLS </a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="accident-at-work.html"> ACCIDENT AT WORK <span class="sr-only">(current)</span> </a>
                </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item col-xs-12 col-md-3">
            <a class="nav-link" href="work-with-us.html"> WORK WITH US </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item col-xs-12 col-md-1">
            <a class="nav-link" href="contact.php"> CONTACT </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item col-xs-12">
            <a class="nav-link hidden-md-up" href="#">
                <i class="nav-link__icon fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item col-xs-12">
            <a class="nav-link hidden-md-up" href="https://twitter.com/search?src=typd&amp;q=legal%20active%20ltd">
                <i class="nav-link__icon fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item col-xs-12">
            <a class="nav-link hidden-md-up" href="#">
                <i class="nav-link__icon fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="submitMessage col-xs-12">
          <h5 class="submitMessage__h5 h5"> THANK YOU </h5>
        <p class="submitMessage__p p"> A member of our team will be in touch with you shortly </p>
        <a class="submitMessage__link link" href="index.php"> Back to homepage </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>




    <!-- Footer -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <nav class="navbar bg-footer">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav footer__nav">
                    <img class="footer__nav__logo col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3 pull-xs-right pull-md-left" src="../../assets/legal-active-logo-large.png" alt="Logo"/>
                    <li class="footer__nav-item nav-item col-xs-12 col-md-5 pull-xs-right"> Legal Active</li>
                    <li class="footer__nav-item nav-item col-xs-12 col-md-5 pull-xs-right"> Magnus House, 8 Ashfield Road, Cheadle, Cheshire, SK8 1BB </li>
                    <li class="footer__nav-item nav-item col-xs-12 col-md-5 pull-xs-right"> Registered in England &amp; Wales - Company No. 123 4567</li>
                    <li class="footer__nav-item nav-item col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-5 pull-xs-right"> All Rights Reserved &copy; Legal Active </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>




    <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script src="../../scss/bootstrap-4/js/tests/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../scss/bootstrap-4/js/tests/vendor/tether.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../scss/bootstrap-4/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../js/custom-js.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can see my other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40793025/1960558

Comment: What is wrong? Do you get an error? Is the mail not sent? What do you want help with?

Comment: Are you posting the form to thank-you.php or contact.php? from your code, the form is posting to thank-you.php, is the php mailing function written in thank-you.php?

Comment: The mail is not being received. The form data is in contact.php. When the user submits the form, they will redirected to thank-you.php. There is no php code in thank-you.php.

Comment: thats the problem, you are posting the form to thank-you.php (action="thank-you.php") but there're no php mailing function in there, of course it wont work, try either putting the php mailing function in thank-you.php, or action="contact.php"

Comment: I have moved the php code from contact.php to thank-you.php but I am still not receiving the email.

Comment: another error is the "$_POST['submit']" is undefined, there're no submit input from the form

Comment: I have now defined $_POST['submit']. The thank-you page now says it has been sent at the top left of the page, however there is nothing in my inbox. You can see this at the domain: sukhysingh.co.uk/contact (after submitting the form)